# Locally nilpotent ideal

Tags: number-theory

Let $A$ be a ring with unity and $J$ an ideal of $R$ such that for any $j \in J$, for some positive integer $n$, $j^n = 0$ Define elements $x,y \in A$ such that $y = x^2$. Prove that for some integer $m$, $x^m y^m =0$.

My attempt: I'm new to this so not sure where to start, to prove $x^m y^m =0$. I thought I would start by saying that $xy \in A$ since $A$ is a ring and if $J$ is an ideal then $j(xy)\in J$ which means that $(j(xy))^n =0$ but not sure where to go from here

Answer (score 1):

This answers all your questions.You have that $x-x^2=x(1-x)=xy\in I$. Hence $(xy)^m=0$ for some $m$. But $xy=x(1-x)=(1-x)x=yx$. So $(xy)^m=x^my^m=0$.

Now since $I$ is an ideal, $x-x^2\in I$ implies $x^2-x^3\in I$, so $x-x^3\in I$. Continue in that manner, you get for every $n$ that $x-x^n\in I$, so $x\in x^n+I$.

Similarly $y\in I+y^m$ because $y^2=(1-x)^2=1-x-x+x^2\in y+I$. Then $x^m+y^m=x+y+r=1+r$ where $r\in I$.  Since $r^k=0$ for some $k$, we have $(1+r)(1-r+r^2-r^3+...\pm r^{k-1})=1$. So $x^m+y^m$ is invertible.

Comment: @BethanyMoeller: $x-x^2\in I$ by the assumption. Also $x-x^2=x(1-x)=xy$.

Comment: "and the coset (I+x)∈A/J is idempotent." You sometimes call the ideal $J$ and sometimes $I$.

Comment: The last equality follows from the form of $a$ found in the answer. I am not sure that the claim that $b$ is an idempotent in $A$ is true.

Comment: The fact that $b$ is an idempotent is in fact true. You need $ax^max^m-ax^m$. Since $x,a$ commute it means $aax^{2m}=ax^m$ which is equivalent to $ax^{2m}=x^m$ which is equivalent to $x^{2m}=x^m a^{-1}$ which is the same as $x^{2m}=x^m(x^m+y^m)$ which is true.